# Error al tratar de usar drawer layout

Tags: android

estaba tratando de usar drawer layout en android amigos pero obtengo el siguiente error cuando quiero obtener la view del contenido principal

```
Unresolved reference: NavigationView
```

No entiendo lo que ocurre, este error me lo lanza cuando invoco al metodo:

```
findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigation_nav_controller)
```

NavigationView si existe y es una clase de la librería para material design de android y no entiendo, ya deberia tenerla incluida porque en el xml agrego bien el nav view

Comment: Hola Pablo, podrias agregar el xml donde le seteas el id al NavigationView y tambien indicar en que metodo estas haciendo el findViewById. Asi en el aire podrian ser muchas cosas, como que este mal el nombre del id o que lo estes buscando antes de que se haya cargado el xml